# Composer cannot resolve requirements to install packages

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I just installed composer globally, along with laravel, I ran laravel new projectname, but php artisan is not working.

I tried composer install and composer update, and I get the following error:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

[image]

I did some research on stackoverflow, and an answer to a post said that there might be no trivial solution for this, and that this is one of the worst features in composer, I installed laravel on windows and never had this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need php-xml and php-mbstring extension that can be installed using

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
```

To enable php-mbstring

```
sudo phpenmod mbstring
```

Then, you will need to restart Apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Other Laravel issues, that you may face during installation can be seen [Here](https://askubuntu.com/a/767970)

Comment: Didn't work composer update returns other problems/errors, composer install returns one less error. Installation request for phpunit code-coverage is gone.

Comment: Which Ubuntu and PHP version you are using ?

Comment: ubuntu 16.04 LTS 32bit and php 7.1.8

Comment: It is fixed, so Linux just doesn't install those missing packages/extensions manually and i have to do it manually? Thanks a lot.